# Website url while enabling places API

Tags: api, google-places-api

in my android application I want to use google places API. I logon to [code.google.com/apis/console](http://code.google.com/apis/console). When I'm trying to enabling access to places API it asks for Company url and organization. I don't have any website, So how do I use it?

I asked my friends, and give their url and name. Now it will show error message as Invalid website url. Please help me to enable the places API service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `URL`. I omit the `"http://"` before the `URL`. Now it solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still care, but you probably just left out "http://" before the URL. This causes it to say "invalid website URL". Very annoying, I know.